# Skew-symmetry on Lie algebras over a field with characteristic not 2

Tags: lie-algebras

I´d like to see the proof (I know it could be elemental) of this fact:

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over a field $\mathbb{F}$ with characteristic not 2. Then $[x,x]=0$ for any $x \in L$ if and only if$ [x,y]=−[y,x]$.

Thank you all

Comment: I'd like to see your work (I know it could be elemental) on this fact: 
Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over a field $\mathbb{F}$ with characteristic not 2. Then $[x,x]=0$ for any $x \in L$ if and only if$ [x,y]=−[y,x]$.

Comment: ... and/or the source of the question (text (name and author and publication date)) and the subject you are studying, and your mathematical background, and/or an explanation as ti what motivated you to ask this question and how it is relevant to you and users on this site.  Actually, please read [How to ask a good question on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), as it well help you edit and improve this question after it is closed.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that this not what you really want to ask, since the equivalence of those two conditions holds by the simple fact that both conditions hold for *any* Lie algebra.

However, for *any* algebra $(A,\star)$ over a field $F$ whose characteristic is not $2$, it is true that the conditions

1. $(\forall x,y\in A):x\star x=0$;
2. $(\forall x,y\in A):x\star y=-y\star x$

are equivalent. In fact, if the second conditions holds and if $x\in A$, then $x\star x=-x\star x$, which means that $2x\star x=0$. SInce the characteistic is not $2$, it follows from this that $x\star x=0$. And if the first condition holds, then, if $x,y\in A$,\begin{align}0&=(x+y)\star(x+y)\\&=x\star x+x\star y+y\star x+y\star y\\&=x\star y+y\star x\end{align}and therefore $x\star y=-y\star x$.

Answer (score 4):

If $[x,x]=0$ for al $x$ then $0=[x+y,x+y]=[x,x]+[x,y]+[y,x]+[y,y]=[x,y]+[y,x],$ so $[x,y]=-[y,x].$

Conversely, if $[x,y]=-[y,x]$ for all $x,y$ then $[x,x]=-[x,x],$ so $2[x,x]=0.$ Since $F$ has characteristic not 2 then $[x,x]=0.$